# Magento Developer mode not working - still trying to load pub/static

Tags: magento2, static-content, developer-mode

Enabling developer mode in magento is giving some errors for me, it is still trying to load all my static content. Ive disabled the "sign static content" option.

Also, when I put my Magento environment in production mode, the fonts in my design/frontend/vendor/theme/web/fonts folder are not moved to the static content.

Any thoughts?

Answer (score 4):

When running in `developer` mode, files will still be loading from the `pub/static` folder. The difference is that some magic in the `pub/static/.htaccess` file routes the request to the `pub/static.php` file, which generates symlinks to populate the `pub/static` directories with your files, on demand. So, one possible way to fix `developer` mode is:

1. If you are running Apache, make sure you didn't delete `pub/static/.htaccess`, and make sure Apache is configured to use `.htaccess` files.
2. If you are running Nginx, make sure the site configuration is correct also. You can look at the `nginx.conf.sample` file for examples of how to set up the `/static/` rewrite.

I'm not sure about what's going on with the fonts in `production` mode if running `bin/magento setup:static-content:deploy` isn't moving them.

Maybe try to clear all your caches, then run `setup:static-content:deploy` again:

1. `bin/magento cache:clean`
2. `rm -r var/view_preprocessed/*`
3. `rm -r var/page_cache/*`
4. `rm -r pub/static/*`

Comment: Hey thanks for replying. I replaced the .htaccess with another one, and developer mode works like it should again, which is weird since I've never made any changes to it. As for the fonts, they are being generated to pub/static/frontend/vendor/theme/nl_NL/fonts, instead of pub/static/frontend/vendor/theme/web. Do you know what could be the cause of this?

Comment: @perrivdb That path, `pub/static/frontend/vendor/theme/nl_NL/fonts`, looks correct. The deploy methods publish everything in the `app/design/frontend/vendor/theme/web` directory to the `pub/static/frontend/vendor/theme/local_CODE` directory (where `local_CODE` is `nl_NL` in this case). For instance `app/design/frontend/vendor/theme/web/images/logo.jpg` is published to `pub/static/frontend/vendor/theme/nl_NL/images/logo.jpg`, etc. This is where M2 expects them, so methods like `$block->getViewFileUrl('images/logo.jpg')` work.

Comment: Then why does my Magento installation look for the fonts in the 'pub/static/frontend/vendor/theme/web/fonts' folder?

Comment: Where are those font paths being requested from? A style sheet I assume? Which one?

Comment: Found the problem! Font paths in my .scss stylesheet were directing to the font directory in app/design, not taking into account what path they would be inside the pub/static folder. Solution was to fix the font path in my scss stylesheets. Thanks for the help!

Comment: Glad you can mark this one solved! Cheers